# How to check if a param is true or false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is really racking my brain, but maybe I'm trying to hard.

I'm passing a param via a URL (example.com?debug=true)

So I basically want to say:

```
if params[:debug] == true
 do xyz
else
 do abc
end
```

But for whatever reason that if statement just isn't doing like it seems like it should.

Is there a better way to do that if/else statement based on a param being true or false?

The debug param will either have a value of true, no value, or a value of false (as far as the URL goes).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

params come in as strings, so you need to compare against `"true"`, not `true`.

Comment: That was the problem...wasn't comparing as a string.

Comment: another solution is to check for it's presence `if params[:debug].present?`

Comment: @Dty For `nil` and `false` the method `.present?` returns `false`. It is the exact opposite of `.blank?`.

Comment: @SparK the answer here says params come in as strings. If `params[:debug]` is the string "false" it will be present (i.e. evaluated incorrectly).

Comment: @Dty in that case, yes... I'm not sure if the parameter will ever come as "false" or will simply be omitted...

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Was stuck on this for more than an hour. Thanks!!

Answer (score 38):

You could use ActiveRecord's method of checking truthful values if you don't want to reinvent the wheel (this is what is used when passing params inside an ActiveRecord object

**Rails 3-4.1**

```
if ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(params[:debug])
    do xyz
else
    do abc
```

**Rails 4.2.0**

```
ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(params[:debug])
```

**Rails 5**

```
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(params[:debug])
```

Might be worth wrapping in a helper but never the less it's quite flexible:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
1.9.3p194 :001 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean '1'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :002 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean '0'
 => false 
1.9.3p194 :003 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean 1
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :004 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean true
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :005 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean 'true'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :006 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean 'on'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :007 > ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean 'off'
```

**Custom extension**

Some people frown on extending core classes but this does fit with the DRY principle.

```
# config/initializer/boolean.rb
class Boolean
  def self.parse(value)
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
  end
end
```

Then used like

```
if Boolean.parse(params[:debug])
  then xyz
```

Comment: It seems that this is not part of the public api as of Rails 4: http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Looks still there to me https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2eae0e80c1916b7cb2e0122f919ef44bb0597fde/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb#L194

Answer (score 8):

Since Rails/ActiveRecord 4.2.0 it is

```
if ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user params[:debug]
  do xyz
else
  do abc
end
```

In Rails 5 it is:

```
if ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast params[:debug]
  do xyz
else
  do abc
end
```

Answer (score 5):

> But for whatever reason that if statement just isn't doing like it seems like it should.

I can almost guarantee that it is doing exactly what it should.  When things don't make sense, one of our assumptions is wrong.

Is the value actually a boolean or is it string (or something else?).  If the value is a string then of course the comparison to the *boolean* value true will fail.  Try comparing to 'true' and see if that works.

Comment: Contradictions do not exist. Whenever you think you are facing a contradiction, check your premises. You will find that one of them is wrong.  (:

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
params[:debug].to_s.downcase == 'true'
```