# String "true" and "false" to boolean

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application and I'm using jQuery to query my search view in the background. There are fields `q` (search term), `start_date`, `end_date` and `internal`. The `internal` field is a checkbox and I'm using the `is(:checked)` method to build the url that is queried:

```
$.getScript(document.URL + "?q=" + $("#search_q").val() + "&start_date=" + $("#search_start_date").val() + "&end_date=" + $("#search_end_date").val() + "&internal=" + $("#search_internal").is(':checked'));
```

Now my problem is in `params[:internal]` because there is a string either containing "true" or "false" and I need to cast it to boolean. Of course I can do it like this:

```
def to_boolean(str)
     return true if str=="true"
     return false if str=="false"
     return nil
end
```

But I think there must be a more Ruby'ish way to deal with this problem! Isn't there...?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

As far as i know there is no built in way of casting strings to booleans,
but if your strings only consist of `'true'` and `'false'` you could shorten your method to the following:

```
def to_boolean(str)
  str == 'true'
end
```

Comment: just a little modification
str == 'true' || str = '1'

Comment: perhaps str.downcase == 'true' for completeness

Comment: @AMTourky shouldn't it be **str == 'true' || str == '1'** with two "==" ?

Comment: @Lowryder Yes! if using default check_box.

Answer (score 49):

ActiveRecord provides a clean way of doing this.

```
def is_true?(string)
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(string)
end
```

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES` has all of the obvious representations of True values as strings.

Comment: Even simpler, just use `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(string)` (source) http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column/value_to_boolean/class

Comment: Yes, in the latest versions!

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("true")`
=> true
 `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("T")`
=> true

Comment: False value list has been moved to ActiveModel::Type::Boolean in Rails 5

Comment: `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean` seems like a much more suitable path - while `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES` contained "truthy" values, one could argue that it's only incidentally the case, and that values that should be considered truthy for that specific use case but not others could be included. On the other hand, `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean` is apparently designed to be used in a generic way.

Answer (score 24):

#### Security Notice

Note that this answer in its bare form is only appropriate for the other use case listed below rather than the one in the question. While mostly fixed, there have been numerous [YAML related security vulnerabilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+yaml+vulnerability) which were caused by loading user input as YAML.

---

A trick I use for converting strings to bools is [`YAML.load`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html), e.g.:

```
YAML.load(var) # -> true/false if it's one of the below
```

[YAML bool](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html) accepts quite a lot of truthy/falsy strings:

```
y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO
|true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE
|on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF
```

#### Another use case

Assume that you have a piece of config code like this:

```
config.etc.something = ENV['ETC_SOMETHING']
```

And in command line:

```
$ export ETC_SOMETHING=false
```

Now since `ENV` vars are strings once inside code, `config.etc.something`'s value would be the string `"false"` and it would incorrectly evaluate to `true`. But if you do like this:

```
config.etc.something = YAML.load(ENV['ETC_SOMETHING'])
```

it would be all okay. This is compatible with loading configs from .yml files as well.

Comment: That's good if the passed string is under your control. In this question's case, the provided values come from the user's browser and as such, they should be considered unsafe. YAML allows you to serialize/deserialize any Ruby object and this is potentially dangerous. There have been numerous incidents: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=rails+yaml+vulnerability

Comment: @Teoulas, I completely agree with you. In fact, I'm adding a notice so people don't use this in an insecure way.

Answer (score 16):

There isn't any built-in way to handle this (although actionpack might have a helper for that). I would advise something like this

```
def to_boolean(s)
  s and !!s.match(/^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)
end

# or (as Pavling pointed out)

def to_boolean(s)
  !!(s =~ /^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)
end
```

What works as well is to use 0 and non-0 instead of false/true literals:

```
def to_boolean(s)
  !s.to_i.zero?
end
```

Comment: you don't need the guard "s and ..." if you use "!!(s =~ /regex_here/)" because "nil =~ /anything/" returns nil.

Comment: Ah indeed. I added it but kept the old as well, as I think the `.match` is a little bit easier to read.

Answer (score 8):

`ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user` does this according to Rails' internal mappings `ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES` and `ConnectionAdapters::Column::FALSE_VALUES`:

```
[3] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("true")
=> true
[4] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("false")
=> false
[5] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("T")
=> true
[6] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("F")
=> false
[7] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("yes")
DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not explicitly `true` or `false` ("yes") to a boolean column. Currently this value casts to `false`. This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will cast to `true` in Rails 5. If you would like to maintain the current behavior, you should explicitly handle the values you would like cast to `false`. (called from <main> at (pry):7)
=> false
[8] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user("no")
DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not explicitly `true` or `false` ("no") to a boolean column. Currently this value casts to `false`. This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will cast to `true` in Rails 5. If you would like to maintain the current behavior, you should explicitly handle the values you would like cast to `false`. (called from <main> at (pry):8)
=> false
```

So you could make your own `to_b` (or `to_bool` or `to_boolean`) method in an initializer like this:

```
class String
  def to_b
    ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: It is ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value) in Rails 5 (see CWitty below)

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5 you can use `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)` to cast it to a boolean.

Comment: be aware though, ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast("42") returns true

Answer (score 6):

You can use wannabe_bool gem.
https://github.com/prodis/wannabe_bool

This gem implements a `#to_b` method for String, Integer, Symbol and NilClass classes.

```
params[:internal].to_b
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `str.to_s.downcase == 'true'` for completeness. Then nothing can crash even if `str` is nil or 0.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anything like that is built-in in Ruby. You can reopen String class and add to_bool method there:

```
class String
    def to_bool
        return true if self=="true"
        return false if self=="false"
        return nil
    end
end
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your project, like this: `params[:internal].to_bool`

Comment: I definitely wouldn't want to have a `to_bool` function return `nil`; that seems wrong. Other conversion functions don't do this: `"a".to_i` returns `0`, not `nil`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code of [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/blob/master/lib/virtus/coercion/string.rb#L84), I'd maybe do something like this:

```
def to_boolean(s)
  map = Hash[%w[true yes 1].product([true]) + %w[false no 0].product([false])]
  map[s.to_s.downcase]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider only appending `internal` to your url if it is true, then if the checkbox isn't checked and you don't append it `params[:internal]` would be `nil`, which evaluates to false in Ruby.

I'm not that familiar with the specific jQuery you're using, but is there a cleaner way to call what you want than manually building a URL string? Have you had a look at `$get` and `$ajax`?

Answer (score 1):

You could add to the String class to have the method of to_boolean. Then you could do 'true'.to_boolean or '1'.to_boolean

```
class String
  def to_boolean
    self == 'true' || self == '1'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -5):

I'm surprised no one posted this simple solution. That is if your strings are going to be "true" or "false".

```
def to_boolean(str)
    eval(str)
end
```

Comment: Thats because This solution is a security Desaster. :D

Comment: The problem with this solution is user input - if someone types `to_boolean("ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DROP TABLE *')")` , it'll destroy your database (and return true!). Have fun :D

Comment: Good points. I wasn't thinking of the context. I was thinking the least amount of characters to implement. :)

Comment: An easy fix for said vulnerability: `bool = nil; bool = eval(str) if ["true", "false"].include?(str)` Just thought I should add for the sake of clarifications.