# Convert XML string to hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I using some service that returns xml:

```
response = HTTParty.post(service_url)
response.parsed_response 
=> "\n\t<Result>\n<success>\ntrue\n</success>\n</Result>"
```

I need to convert this string to hash. Something like this:

```
response.parsed_response.to_hash
=> {:result => { :success => true } }
```

Which way to do this?

Comment: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/08/11/parsing-xml-with-ruby/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The built-in [`from_xml`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/from_xml/class) Rails `Hash` method will do precisely what you want. In order to get your `response.parsed_response` correctly mapped to a hash, you'll need to `gsub()` out the newlines:

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(response.parsed_response.gsub("\n", "")) 
hash #=> {"Result"=>{"success"=>"true"}}
```

In the context of parsing a hash in Rails, objects of `String` type are [not substantively different](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/) than those of `Symbol` from a general programming perspective. However, you can apply the Rails `symbolize_keys` method to the output:

```
symbolized_hash = hash.symbolize_keys
#=> {:Result=>{"success"=>"true"}}
```

As you can see, `symbolize_keys` doesn't operate on any nested hashes, but you could potentially iterate through inner hashes and apply `symbolize_keys`.

The final piece of the puzzle is to convert the string `"true"` to the boolean `true`. AFAIK, there's no way to do this on your hash in place, but if you're iterating/operating on it, you could potentially implement a solution like the one [suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119970/string-true-and-false-to-boolean):

```
def to_boolean(str)
     return true if str == "true"
     return false if str == "false"
     return nil
end
```

Basically, when you reach the inner key-value pair, you'd apply `to_boolean()` to the value, which is currently set to `"true"`. In your example, the return value is the boolean `true`.

Comment: Just FYI, Rails has a [deep_symbolize_keys](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) method, so you don't need to iterate through inner hashes

Answer (score 12):

Use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to parse XML response to ruby hash. It's pretty fast.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'  #from_xml 
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(response_body)
Hash.from_xml(doc.to_s)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this below:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'  
str = "\n\t<Result>\n<success>\ntrue\n</success>\n</Result>".gsub("\n", "").downcase

Hash.from_xml(str)
# => {"result"=>{"success"=>"true"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for including the require to use in ruby outside rails!

Answer (score 3):

Use gem [Nokogir](http://nokogiri.org/)

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)

data = doc.xpath("//Result").map do |result|
  [
    result.at("success").content
  ]
end
```

These [tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) may help you.

Comment: hope it will not give exact hash as i got `#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x16e3790 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x16e32e0 name="result" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x16e30ec name="success" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x16e2de0 "true">]>]>]>`

Answer (score 1):

I found a gem which does exactly that:

```
gem 'actionpack-xml_parser'
```

Basically, each node represents a key. With the following XML:

```
<person><name>David</name></person>
```

The resulting parameters will be:

```
{"person" => {"name" => "David"}}
```

https://github.com/eileencodes/actionpack-xml_parser