# ActiveRecord string booleans as query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to query my database with a boolean type that is passed to me through the controller as a string. What Rails attempts to do is the following:

```
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."complete" = ?  [["complete", "false"]]
```

This yields an empty array which should not be the case. Having tried manually retrieving records via the rails console, I come up with the same results. However substituting "false" for "f" solves the problem.

It is not an ideal solution to use "f" as a substitute because I am using emberjs and the boolean type in my frontend models which by default sends up "true" or "false"

Why wont ActiveRecord accept full booleans as string and how can I make it do so?

Comment: what is your activerecord query?

Comment: @orders = Order.where(complete: false) where false comes from the paras hash

Comment: can you try this `@orders = Order.where("complete = ?", false)`

Comment: That gives me what I want, but you see false will be given to me as a string in the params hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you can't really do this without a helper of some kind. See the selected answer here:

[String "true" and "false" to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119970/string-true-and-false-to-boolean)

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. Thanks for the reply. I shall just intercept the boolean in the params hash and convert it before I make the query