# Rails 4: Pass boolean value on new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The goal is to pass a specific boolean value (true or false) with a specific link.

I've tried with:

```
<%= link_to "new test", new_test_path(:crazy => true) %>
```

> URL: **/tests/new?crazy=true**

view

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.radio_button :crazy, true %> True
  <%= f.radio_button :crazy, false %> False
</div>
```

static_pages_controller

```
def home
  @test = Test.new
  ...
end
```

but none of the radio buttons is selected when I click on that link.

Comment: You need to set the value of the attribute to be true in the controller.  If it's `true`, the first button will check.  If it's `false`, the second button will check. It's probably `nil`.

Comment: Could you please write an answer to see how to actually do it? I've tried setting value in test_params with [:crazy => 'true'], but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't get values from query string as Boolean. You will need to check all the possibilities or just do something like:

```
params[:crazy] == 'true'
```

However, string comparison is always costly as per string length. So, you should try to minimize it. You may check centralized method solution given by [Ismriv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14097213/1047207).

---

I guess this will be best for you:

Your link:

```
<%= link_to "new test", new_test_path(:crazy => '1') %>
```

Your `new` action:

```
def new
  @test = Test.new(:crazy => (params[:crazy] == '1'))
  ...
end
```

Your radios:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.radio_button :crazy, true %> True
  <%= f.radio_button :crazy, false %> False
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The radio_button method (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) does not check the radio button automatically based on request parameters.

```
<%= f.radio_button '', :crazy, 'true', { checked: params[:crazy] == 'true' } %> True
<%= f.radio_button '', :crazy, 'false', { checked: params[:crazy] == 'false' } %> False
```

Do note the object_name / method distinction in rails, which generates parameters named "object_name[method]" by convention. If you really want your parameter to only be named "crazy", leave object_name empty.