# why if condition is not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, literals, rubocop

I am testing small code below

```
  params[:code] = if false
                                 'N'
                               else
                                 'Y'
                               end
```

it returns N for if param[:code] passed as true or false also rubucop shows error literal 'false' appeared in a condition. any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "string literal in condition" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556673/what-does-string-literal-in-condition-mean)

Answer (score 2):

## if false

```
params[:code] = if false
                   'N'
                else
                   'Y'
                end
```

This code is just :

```
params[:code] = 'Y'
```

No `if`, not but : `false` is well, always `false`, so there's no way `N` can be reached. That's the reason rubocop is complaining.

## Modified code

I guess you meant to write :

```
params[:code] = if params[:code] == false
                   'N'
                else
                   'Y'
                end
```

It's not rubyish at all, but at least it looks like your code and does what you expect it to.

To test it :

```
params = {code: false}

params[:code] = if params[:code] == false
                   'N'
                else
                   'Y'
                end
p params
# {:code=>"N"}
```

## Warning!

If your `params` values are Strings (as they often are), you'll have to test against Strings :

```
 params[:code] = if params[:code] == "false"
                       'N'
                    else
                       'Y'
                    end
```

With a ternary :

```
params[:code] = params[:code] == "false" ? 'N' : 'Y'
```

Or a hash :

```
params[:code] = {'true' => 'Y', 'false' => 'N'}[params[:code]]
```

If you have a fuzzy input (e.g. `true` or `"true"` or `"True"` or `"yes"`), you could use [Rails built-in methods to convert to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13151083/6419007) :

```
code = ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(params[:code]) # For Rails 4.2
params[:code] = code ? 'Y' : 'N'
```

Comment: thanks. i am trying your modified code but for input value false its assigning param[:code] = Y. are there any other ways? i am using postman for testing http://localhost:3001/D/DB_ID/users/user_id/test?code=false

Comment: @User7354632781: Your localhost is not my localhost, I cannot access your server. Also, is your input value `"false"` (a String) or `false` (a boolean)?

Comment: true or false are boolean

Comment: They might be strings. `param` values are almost always strings unless you're submitting JSON.

Comment: Have you considered changing `if params[:code] == false` to `if !params[:code]`, or better still, `unless params[:code]'?  Explicit comparison to `false` is not idomatic Ruby.  You probably know this, but I'll bet the OP doesn't.

Comment: @WayneConrad: Thanks, I'll update the answer, but I need some more info from OP first.

Comment: this one is working code = params[:code] == 'true' ? 'Y' : 'N'

Comment: @User7354632781 : 'true' is a string, not a boolean. Thanks for the precision. So now, what should be the exact behaviour? What are the possible values for `params[:code]`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this...

```
params[:code] ? 'Y' : 'N'
```

> Or

```
params[:code] = params[:code] ? 'Y' : 'N'
# If you are trying to also re-assign params[:code].
```

Comment: I do not believe that reading the question makes ANYTHING obvious.

Comment: I am passing code value as true and false and based on that update param code value to Y or N.

Comment: Then the second example I provided is the way to go.